# How to use Javascript to check active directory to see if a user is in a memberof a particular group?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, active-directory

I have at my disposal Javascript and Classic ASP.  Using these two how can I check to see if a user is a member of a particular active directory group?  I know VBSCRIPT has memberof function but I can only use javascript.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about JavaScript running in the browser or server-side JScript embedded in the ASP?

Comment: server-side Jscript. So far i've got a ADODB connection with the ADsDSOObject provider.  I was trying to search using maybe a sql command or something to that effect.  a function that returns true or false if the member matches is what im trying to get

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to ensure that your web server is set to use Windows Authentication.  Then you can use Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") to get the current user's domain\username.

You'll then query Active Directory using ADSI to get group membership.

Here's a link to msdn's ADSI pages.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

[This page](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/)  has some sample scripts (in vbscript)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no possibility to access activeDirectory by using Javascript. Javascript runs within the browser - and may not access anything out of this sandbox.

In case I misunderstood your question und you ment server-side checking - use ASP functions to check for.

Comment: I think he's referring to server side javascript with asp.

Comment: I was thinking something aong the lines of using ADO to connect and use a sql type query to check?  I just wasnt sure how to go abou tit

Answer (score 0):

You'll need AJAX and a connection to the AD using ADODB.Connection with the "ADsDSOObject" provider.

**EDIT**:  I saw your comment above.  Here's a start:

```
ldapCommand.CommandText = "select sn from '" & _
    "LDAP://example.com/DC=example,DC=com" & _
    "' WHERE samAccountName=" & "'" & username & "'"

Set ldapRecordSet = ldapCommand.Execute
```

ldapCommand is an ADODB.Command, and if Execute throws an error, then the user is not in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try using Javascript to instantialte a WScript.Network object

```
var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
```

From there, you can get

```
var netWorkUserName = WshNetwork.UserName;
var netWorkDomain = WshNetwork.UserDomain;
```

A word of warning:  I'm pretty sure this is IE only and requires security changes in IE.